# Expected comma - jsonc(514)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-code

vs code show that     "workbench.colorCustomizations": this line has a problem the error is

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations":
{
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: vs code show that "workbench.colorCustomizations": this line has a problem the error is Expected commajsonc(514)

Comment: Did you try adding a comma after the closing curly brace?  We'd have to see more of your file to know if this entry was in fact the last entry, thus not requiring a comma.

Comment: Usually that means that the preceding entry (before `workbench.colorCustomization` is the one that needs a trailing comma.

Comment: That looks like a part of your `settings.json` file from vscode. Try putting the whole thing in a json validator. It looks like it is incorrectly formatted somewhere (missing a comma) and the validator may help you run down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a coma as shown below

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations":
{
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#ffffff",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a trailing comma to the previous entry in the `settings.json` file.